# Coldfusion cfcontent doesn't take me back to my calling page

Tags: coldfusion

I'm calling this from a .cfm page to download the excel file and I have added a loading mask to prevent further clicks on the download button, however, once after downloading it doesn't go back to my .cfm page and never stops the loading masks.

```
cfheader( name="Content-Disposition", value="attachment; filename=#fileName#" );
cfcontent( type="application/vnd.ms-excel", variable="#spreadsheetReadBinary(spreadsheet)#", reset="true" );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you opening a new tab/window to trigger download?

Comment: No, I'm downloading on the same page and that is why I have added the loading mask to prevent multiple clicks. The download and data is working fine but the mask doesn't go away because the cfcontent which is in .cfc file doesn't send back the response.

Comment: Hate to break it to you but,that's how cfcontent works.

Comment: What makes you think the cfc isn't returning a response? Could you show us what you mean by "mask"?

Comment: @Agreax I have a .cfm page which is to download a file, so onSubmit all it does is call a .cfc file where the code is to download using cfcontent, once after the download it never returns back to my .cfm page. Since I started the loading mask onSubmit it never stops loading the mask.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Thank you for confirming me. I didn't find anything written on the website so I just wanted to know if there is a way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get to any redirect command when using `cfcontent`. The response from that command is based on the mime-type of the requested content.

- `application/json`
- `application/xml`
- `application/vnd.ms-excel`

You don't get anything other than that content. In your case, once the file is downloaded, then no more CFML code is run on the page.

If your desired workflow is:

- Click a link
- Download file
- Redirect once the file is downloaded.

then you should

- Click a link that triggers a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request (or `jQuery.ajax()`)
- The download will be done via a separate page.
- The `fetch` can redirect to another page once the file is downloaded.

Odds are, you don't need to actually redirect, you just want the file to download

(Sorry, this has been sitting not posted for a few days.)

Comment: Thank for the response. I only wanted to stop the loading mask. My only intention of using this to prevent a user from submitting it multiple times without waiting for the file to download.